# Facebook Graph API for App Insights Not Returning Latest Results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to query in the Facebook Graph API and it's not returning the latest results. It's giving me data which dates 3 days back (April 11th), and I can't make it return the results which include the last two days (12th or the 13th). When I explicitly set the `since` and `until` parameters to the last two days, it returns no data.

```
=== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/266492440452954/app_insights/facebook_features_daily_active_users?access_token=<access token sanitized>"
=== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "user_birthday",
      "user_about_me",
      "email",
      "read_insights",
      "read_audience_network_insights",
      "manage_pages",
      "public_profile"
    ],
    "user_id": "10101060008646191",
    "app_id": 145634995501895
  }

=== Response
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "time": "2017-04-08T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
      },
      {
        "time": "2017-04-09T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
      },
      {
        "time": "2017-04-10T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "time": "2017-04-11T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "2"
      }
    ],
    "__debug__": {}
  }

=== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=266492440452954%2Fapp_insights%2Ffacebook_features_daily_active_users&version=v2.8
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it seems like the stats are a day behind. It's possible that it's due to a timezone difference, but so far I haven't been able to definitively confirm that it is the case.